# Swift 3.0 UITableViewDelege Objective-c method does not match the requirement's selector

Tags: swift, swift3

I recently converted a project to Swift 3 with Xcode 8.0 and I got a error on a function which I don't understand very well. On these lines:

```
extension HomeTableViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

To resolve the error, Xcode tells me to add `@objc(tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:)` just before the method.

[image: Xcode error]

Okay, it works, but I don't get why it is only required for this method.

Xcode doesn't require to add the @objc stuff in front of my  `tableView:heighForHeaderInSection` but I don't see any differences in the `UITableViewDelegate` between this method and the  `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

So, know why is this mandatory for the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` method ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem for the @objc(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) method. No idea why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are adopting the incorrect protocol in your extension. The `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method is part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. Change your extension to adopt the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol instead of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and the error goes away.

At least this worked for me when I got this error with `NSCollectionViewDelegate/DataSource` extensions.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I didn't notice that! PEBCAK :/ It is strange that it made no warning with Swift 2.2